# Is correct to call a function from a BackGroundWorker?

Tags: vb.net, function, backgroundworker

I have an application that gets data from a database, processes it, and then sends it to a defined IP.  I want to make it use a `BackgroundWorker` to avoid halting the GUI.

The code in the `BackgroundWorker` event handler is too long and complex, so I'm thinking of splitting that code into many functions to better organize the code.

Is this OK? Can I write those functions in the same `Form1` class and call them from a `BackgroundWorker`?  Do I need to create a new class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is perfectly acceptable, if not preferable.  The question is not whether or not you are calling other methods from the `BackgroundWorker` event.  Rather, the question is what those functions actually *do*.  If they are modifying UI controls, that is unacceptable, whether it is done or the event handler or in a separate function.  Similarly, if they use thread-unsafe objects that are being shared with the UI thread without `SyncLock`, then that is a problem too in either place.  So, yes, as long as the work being performed is thread-safe, then it doesn't matter at all if it is done in the event handler, a separate method, or even in another class or library.

For instance, if your method needs to update a `RichTextBox` control from the background thread, you could do something like this:

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    GenerateReport()
End Sub

Private Sub GenerateReport()
    Dim rtf As String = ' ...
    Me.Invoke(Sub() RichTextBox1.Rtf = rtf)
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for your example; I get it clear now. You use a lambda expression on the last line, Right?

Comment: Yes. It's not necessary. You can use a delegate to a normal method, but, as you can see, lambda expressions are particularly useful for this kind of thing.

Comment: So, Can I call the Delegate directly or should I replace "RichTextBox1.Rtf = rtf" by  "WriteRTBLog(rtf,Color)" in the lambda expression?

Comment: Yes, you can just change the lambda expression to call whatever method or set whatever property you want.

Answer (score 1):

A BackgroundWorker can certainly call functions. Just as with the code in the BackgroundWorker's DoWork method, you need to make sure that the code in the function isn't trying to update the same objects that code in the main thread is updating. For example, you need to either avoid updating UI controls, or use a thread-safe way of doing that.

Comment: Currently I have a RichTextBox that I update through a Delegate. I must to avoid to call that delegate too? I use that as a LOG

Comment: Any time you need to touch a UI control, like a `RichTextBox` from a background thread, you need to call the `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` method of the form or control, giving it a delegate to the method that updates the control.

Comment: I don't finish to understand what you are explaining to me. Are you trying to tell me that call the Delegate directly from the BackGroundWorker is not OK and I should perform an Invoke to Form1 and then call the Delegate? I need to make a research on Google, Should I search "Invoke" directly? I don't know if that is going to give me the results that I need to understand you.

Comment: I've updated answer to include an example of using `Invoke` to update a `RichTextBox` from a background thread.